# PhantomJS onResourceReceived returns more results than expected

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using `phantomJS` to get all the Request URLs from the `Network` tab, but I'm also getting additional unwanted requests.

For example, if you go to marvel.com there are 117 requests in the Network tab and my script returns me 142 results, or even more ... is there any way to only get those 117 requests from the network tab?

This is my code:

```
var urls = ["https://marvel.com"];
var page = require('webpage').create();
var links = "";

var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'TestOutput.txt';

function handle_page(url){
  page.open(url,function(){
    fs.write(path, links, 'w');
    next_page();
  });

  page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    if(links.indexOf(response.url) == -1 && response.url.indexOf("http") !== -1) {
      links += response.url + '\n';
    }
  }
  links += '\n';
  links += '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------';
  links += '\n';  
}

function next_page(){
  var url = urls.shift();
  if(!url) {
    phantom.exit(0);
  }
  handle_page(url);
}

next_page();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unwanted"? I opened the site in Chrome and there were 123 requests in the network tab of devtools. How can any of them be either wanted or not?

Comment: I'm wondering why I'm getting more than the number of requests from the network tab...I just want to get the Request URL only from the requests visible in the network tab. Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers behave differently. PhantomJS is a full browser which has nothing to do how Chrome operates.

The [`page.onResourceReceived` event handler](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html) is triggered twice for most requests (practically all requests that I encountered if the network connection didn't break in the middle). That's because this event handler is triggered once when the first data arrives (`response.stage == "start"`) and when the connection is closed (`response.stage == "end"`).

When we look at the numbers, this means that PhantomJS sees only roughly 71 (maybe a little bit more) requests. That's much less than what Chrome would see. The reason is a bit mysterious, but it seems that many connections to advertisement sites are broken in PhantomJS. Many ads are simply not loaded. This can have many reasons, but you're likely won't be able to fix it.

You could play around with the following [commandline options](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) (newlines and backslashes added for readability):

```
--web-security=false \
--local-to-remote-url-access=true \
--ignore-ssl-errors=true \
--ssl-protocol=any
```